how to columnate list of strings in two lines, aligned to the length of the first column
I have a list of strings:
python2-distutils-extra|==>|python2-distutils-extra|2.39-5|Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-fuse|==>|python2-fuse|1.0.5-1|This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel                                               
python2-gobject2|==>|python2-gobject2|2.28.7-7|Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject                                                                                                                                                                                     
python2-numpy|==>|python2-numpy|1.16.6-3|Scientific tools for Python 2

I want to get:
python2-distutils-extra ==> python2-distutils-extra 2.39-5
    Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-fuse            ==> python2-fuse 1.0.5-1
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel                                               
python2-gobject2        ==> python2-gobject2 2.28.7-7
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject                                                                                                                                                                                     
python2-numpy           ==> python2-numpy 1.16.6-3
    Scientific tools for Python 2

edit: aligned to the length of the first column means '==>' is always at the same position (just like in above code).
I've already tried to get it with column, but doesn't matter which options of column I use the result is:
python2-distutils-extra                                                                                                                                                         ==>  python2-distutils-extra    2.39-5        
    Enhancements to the Python build system                                                                                                                                                                                  
python2-fuse                                                                                                                                                                    ==>  python2-fuse               1.0.5-1       
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel                                               
python2-gobject2                                                                                                                                                                ==>  python2-gobject2           2.28.7-7      
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject                                                                                                                                                                                     
python2-numpy                                                                                                                                                                   ==>  python2-numpy              1.16.6-3      
    Scientific tools for Python 2

Please, help...

awk -F'|' '{print $1" "$4"\n   "$5}' file?

Thank you for your comment.
Will this command (or maybe after a modification) align my separator (==>) with the longest text in first column?

Check if column -s '|' -t file is enough, or adjusting with awk, something like awk -F'|' '{printf("%-30s %s %s %s \n %s \n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5);}'

(1) Please [edit] your question to explain the “aligned to the first column” requirement,  (2) … and say what should happen if a subsequent input line has a longer value in the first column.

@G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica' i'd like to get the output like I showed. You're right, the list is generated by rest of the script and always i'd like to get output with the '==>' position of longest text from first column.

With awk, column and sed:
$ awk -F'|' '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3" "$4"|"$5 }' foo.txt | column -ts$'\t' | sed 's/|/\n\t/'
python2-distutils-extra  ==>  python2-distutils-extra 2.39-5
    Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-fuse             ==>  python2-fuse 1.0.5-1
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel
python2-gobject2         ==>  python2-gobject2 2.28.7-7
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject
python2-numpy            ==>  python2-numpy 1.16.6-3
    Scientific tools for Python 2


Thank you schrodingerscatcuriosity. This works perfect!

With GNU awk; I didn't strip the trailing whitespace in each line as you didn't, either:
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{longest=0} NR==FNR{if(length($1)>longest){longest=length($1)}} FNR!=NR {printf "%-"longest"s %s %s %s\n    %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' list list
python2-fuse            ==> python2-fuse 1.0.5-1
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel
python2-distutils-extra ==> python2-distutils-extra 2.39-5
    Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-gobject2        ==> python2-gobject2 2.28.7-7
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject
python2-numpy           ==> python2-numpy 1.16.6-3
    Scientific tools for Python 2


Thank you for your answer. That's almost what I need! It works perfect if the following names in first column are shorter than prevoiusly checked one. Is it possible to test all names before printing them? If so, how?

Ooops ... sorry, small mistake in my script. Will edit it now @ludvick I reordered the longest line down for testing.

Using any POSIX awk:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="\t" }
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    wid = ( length($1) > wid ? length($1) : wid )
    vals[NR] = $0
}
END {
    for ( i=1; i<=NR; i++ ) {
        $0 = vals[i]
        printf "%-*s %s %s %s\n    %s\n", wid, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
python2-distutils-extra ==> python2-distutils-extra 2.39-5
    Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-fuse            ==> python2-fuse 1.0.5-1
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel
python2-gobject2        ==> python2-gobject2 2.28.7-7
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject
python2-numpy           ==> python2-numpy 1.16.6-3
    Scientific tools for Python 2

The only notable difference between the above and @tink's answer as that this stores all of the input in memory and so would fail if the input was massive (@schrodingerscatcuriosity also stores all the input in memory, in column instead of in awk, and that apparently works for you so I assume that's not a problem) but it's only reading the input once and so would work if the input was coming from a pipe instead of stored in a file.
The difference between this and @schrodingerscatcuriosity's answer is that this would work if your input contained tabs while theirs wouldn't, but that seems unlikely.
The gsub() above is stripping any leading/trailing white space from your input as it seems unlikely you'd want that retained in the output.

Using Miller (mlr) to convert the input from a pipe-delimited headerless CSV format to "pretty-printed" tabular format, while also prepending the last field with a newline and four spaces:
$ mlr --c2p -N --ifs pipe put '$[NF] = "\n    " . $[NF]' file
python2-distutils-extra ==> python2-distutils-extra 2.39-5   
    Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-fuse            ==> python2-fuse            1.0.5-1  
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel
python2-gobject2        ==> python2-gobject2        2.28.7-7 
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject
python2-numpy           ==> python2-numpy           1.16.6-3 
    Scientific tools for Python 2

This also aligns the versions.
Breaking the long lines of the last field into lines of at most 40 characters using fold, and indenting each line with four spaces:
$ mlr --c2p -N --ifs pipe put '$[NF] = "\n    " . gssub(exec("fold",["-w","40","-s"],{"stdin_string": $[NF]}),"\n","\n    ")' file
python2-distutils-extra ==> python2-distutils-extra 2.39-5   
    Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-fuse            ==> python2-fuse            1.0.5-1  
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse 
    (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a 
    simple interface for userspace programs 
    to export a virtual filesystem to the 
    Linux kernel
python2-gobject2        ==> python2-gobject2        2.28.7-7 
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject
python2-numpy           ==> python2-numpy           1.16.6-3 
    Scientific tools for Python 2

Note that this calls fold once for each record.

Solution in TXR:
python2-distutils-extra => python2-distutils-extra 2.39-5
    Enhancements to the Python build system
python2-fuse            => python2-fuse 1.0.5-1
    This is a Python 2 interface to libfuse (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse), a simple interface for userspace programs to export a virtual filesystem to the Linux kernel
python2-gobject2        => python2-gobject2 2.28.7-7
    Legacy Python 2 bindings for GObject
python2-numpy           => python2-numpy 1.16.6-3
    Scientific tools for Python 2

In packages.txr we have:
@(collect)
@name1|==>|@name2|@ver|@desc
@(end)
@(bind colwidth @[find-max-key name1 : len])
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@{name1 colwidth} => @name2 @ver
    @(trim-str desc)
@  (end)
@(end)

